# How can I pull data from Google Analytics to see the top pages visited from the current page?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I would like to create a small sidebar on each page of my website that contains `related/popular pages` with perhaps the top five pages users visit after reading the current page.

I could track and record user movements across the site myself and build the list that way, but as my site already uses Google Analytics and I know the data is there I'd rather access that if all possible.

The trouble is that I don't have the faintest idea whether it is possible or not.

Comment: [Analytics Core Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the [Google Analytics Reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference) is not real-time it can take between 24 - 48 hours for the data to finish processing and be in the API for you to request.

The [Realtime Google Analytics api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/) is real time but the data is only about 5 minutes old and its very limited to the [dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/) you can request.

Quota, with either of those APIs you are limited to 10,000 requests per day per profile / view.  I have no idea how many pages there are on your site or how may users are on your site but this could quickly blow out this NON extendable quota.

Options:  Except that its not realtime data and use the reporting api every night run a request against the api get everything for two days ago then show your users on your site data that's two days old.  Store the data in the database then you are showing them data on in your DB and wont have an issue with the quota as you only requested it once.

But this isn't exactly what you want as its not showing a users activity over the site.  TBH I am not sure you can exactly use Google Analytics to track a user as the data is user non specific.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A weekly or monthly update would be fine, I don't expect to pull this data on every page load - that would probably slow the pages down quite a bit. But I would get quite accurate results about user behaviour and this would be a nice learning experience for me.

As for tracking users, all I need to do is look at the flow I believe, and look at the top five pages. I basically need [this](http://i.imgur.com/lmOXJgP.png) data, whereby I can look at each page and see the top five pages visited from that page.

Comment: This should get you started.  You want to use a Service account for this not Oauth2 http://www.daimto.com/google_service_account_php/

Comment: Okay, I followed your tutorial and can pull some basic data out for a range of dates. Progress!

Now, how do I go about requesting the top 5 pages people navigate to from the current page?

Comment: Good question I would test your requests with this https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/   maybe do a bit of research on Google analytics how it groups stuff by sessions.  http://www.morevisibility.com/blogs/analytics/hidden-google-analytics-gems-navigation-summary-and-entrance-paths.html

Comment: Hmm, that's a bit much for someone completely new to this. The documentation might be good for someone who lives and breathes SEO/GA but to me it's not at all clear. Looking through some of the possible parameters I'm not even convinced that I can generate the views that I want.

Comment: I have been playing with it as well.   I think its possible, and its a great idea.  I just haven't managed to get it to work exactly yet.

Comment: Well at least I know my idea is great. I'm still reading up but I doubt that I am going to arrive at an answer without a great deal of research and learning. Mind sharing what you have so far and let me know if you find a way to do this?

Comment: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2014-12-01&end-date=2014-12-31&metrics=ga%3Asessions&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath%2Cga%3ApreviousPagePath%2Cga%3AnextPagePath&filters=ga%3ApreviousPagePath!%3D(entrance)

Comment: I have something like it on my website I think it runs by checking categories.  but it uses wordpress not Google analytics

Comment: Ah, that was definitely getting towards what I wanted. I have amended it a bit more to exclude pages with parameters (?), not ideal but not sure how to merge all of the pages and ignore the url params...

https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-05-01&end-date=2015-05-14&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath%2Cga%3ApreviousPagePath&filters=ga%3ApreviousPagePath!%40%3F%3Bga%3ApreviousPagePath!%3D(entrance)

Comment: just rip everything you might want from the API dump it in your Database and process it after.

Comment: I believe the technical term for that is [judo](https://signalvnoise.com/posts/312-lingo-judo) ;)

Comment: Any idea why ga:sessions is returning no results, but ga:users is? [Link to current search](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/query-explorer/?start-date=2015-05-01&end-date=2015-05-31&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath%2Cga%3ApreviousPagePath&filters=ga%3ApreviousPagePath!%3D(entrance))

Comment: I have data for that report

Comment: Marking as correct because our long commentary has led me to the answer in the end. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get involved with learning the API and develop this from the ground up, check out [EmbeddedAnalytics](http://www.embeddedanalytics.com/) *(disclaimer: I created the service)*.   We could provide such a widget.

You may find [This Article](http://www.analyticsedge.com/2014/09/misunderstood-metrics-next-page-path/) useful.  It provides the necessary query to find the "next page visited" using the page of interest as a filter.  Ultimately your query would look like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3Aabc&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews&dimensions=ga%3ApreviousPagePath%2Cga%3AnextPagePath&sort=-ga%3Apageviews&filters=ga%3ApreviousPagePath%3D%40pricing
```

The query above will give you the "Next Page" along with pageviews assuming the "previous" page contains the word "pricing".

We could easily build such report widget for you:

- You would insert a javascript source code snippet into your page.  The javascript would pass the page url to our server and we would return the next "most popular pages visited".
- The pages could be "linkified" so that someone could click the link to go to that page.
- We already have caching mechanism in place.  So each pageview would not require a new query to google (making it quicker and also staying away from the API quota that was mentioned above).  For pages that are hardly ever looked at (e.g. less than once a week), we could make "on-demand" calls to get the statistics.
- In my experience with the API, the lag in the API is only a couple hours.  It may be longer for larger sites.

Please let me know if you are interested in such widget and I can work with you.